MATLAB/Simulink: How to calculate the knee angle from a Dynamic model of a prosthesis leg?
Given the following Dynamic model:
Dynamic model
m_2,l_1,l_c2,I_2,g,theta_1,_2 are known
Only theta_2 is unknown, but we know what it's supposed to look like (theta_2ref)
I built this model to calculate theta_2:
Simulink model
but I'm getting this result:
resulted theta_2
but theta_2ref should look like this:
theta_2ref
what am I doing wrong? is checked the model multiple times but couldn't find the answer.
I repositioned D2R after the derivatives and the result changed a bit in magnitude but still has the same oscillating shape.
I used the default settings in the Integrators and Derivatives blocks.
I used timeseries to input _2 (which I named T2 in the model) and theta_1, is there another way to feed the model those inputs?
ddt2 block:
(u(1)-m2l1lc2cos(u(2)-u(3))u(5)+m2l1lc2sin(u(2)-u(3))(u(4)^2)-(m2lc2gsin(u(3))))/(I2+m2lc2^2)
constants:
m1=1.02;m2=2.36;l1=0.460;l2=0.430;lc1=0.360;lc2=0.165;
I1=0.356;I2=0.078;g=9.82;lCD=0.240;lCB=0.045;

_2 (T2) input:
_2
theta_1 input:
theta_1
